How to start react-native application with geolocation?
my directory structure is enter image description here
And I want to start My Awesomeproject.
But Error is bothering me.
Error message is
enter image description here
package.json isenter image description here
I tried "react-native start --reset-cache"
But it said
'react-native' is not an internal or external console, executable program, or
It's not a batch file.


Have you tried to install the react native cli with npm install -g react-native-cli?
Don't forget to restart the command prompt to get react-native command working.

Use npm install -g react-native-cli to install react-native-cli
Don't forget to restart the command prompt to get react-native command working
